# RestAssured - how to send a request without Content-Type?

Tags: rest-assured

I am using RestAssured to send a request:

```
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("Accept", "*/*");
    headers.put("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    headers.put("Connection", "keep-alive");

    Response response = RestAssured.given().baseUri(BASE_URL)
            .headers(headers)
            .log().all()
            .post(URL_PREFIX + "/documents/request/" + username);
```

However, in the log I see that 1 more header was automatically added:

```
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

And I get 415 error.
Is it possible to send a request without Content-Type? I mean, without this header at all; if the request is sent with Content-Type equal to empty line, there is still a 400 error; the only way to make it work is to send the request without this header.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a bug in the RestAssured framework that is still open (I verified that in 4.3.3).

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured
testImplementation group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '4.3.3'
```

Founded out, when creating negative tests for a API. Content type below is automatically generated when trying to send request.

```
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Bug defined here:

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/656

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/986